# Adding an extension method to HtmlHelper in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to add an extension method for the html helper to customize a table, i add this method:

```
public static class HtmlElements
    {
        public static string Table(this HtmlHelper ht, string classe)
        {
            var table = new HtmlTable();
            table.Attributes.Add("class", classe);
            return table.InnerHtml;
        }

    }
```

When i'd like to use it like this

```
 @using(@Html.Table("table_data")){
}
```

i have an error which indicates that i have to convert a string to IDisposable type.

1. What are the reasons of this error?
2. How can i fix it?

**Edit**

the full view's code :

```
    using(var table = @Html.Table("table_data")){

        <tr>
             <th>Description</th>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Statut du client</th>
            <th>Etat de test</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    for (int i = Model[2] - 5; i < Model[2]; i++)
    {
        if(i < Model[1].Count)
        {
        <tr style="font-size: 12px; padding:0px; ">
             <td>@Model[0][i].PDescription</td>
            <td>@Model[0][i].Nom_client</td>
             <td>@Model[0][i].Statut_client</td>
             <td style="color:red">@Model[1][i]</td>
             <td>
                @Model[0][i].Statut_client
             </td>
      </tr>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you add extension method for the htmlhelper, not the html table, also see more about [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: why you want `using`? you can move creating html to your helper and return string with generated html, without object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method returns a `string`, and when you use `using` in C#, that means you are insantiating an object that implements `IDisposable`, which `string` does not.

You are not doing anything with the string either. If you intend to build up an HtmlTable and do something with that, you must modify your code, for instance like so:

```
    public static HtmlTable Table(this HtmlHelper ht, string classe)
    {
        var table = new HtmlTable();
        table.Attributes.Add("class", classe);
        return table;
    }
```

and then you must use that in your code, like so:

```
@using(var table = @Html.Table("table_data")){
}
```

and within the brackets, you can now access the variable `table`.

Comment: Thanks @Roy , but it didn't work because : the generated html doesn't contain a table and the css class isn't added to the table

Comment: @Lamloumi: The code above doesn't generate HTML, you still have to add code between the `{` and `}` brackets to do something with the `table` variable.

Comment: @Lamloumi: You don't use the `table` variable anywhere, so of course it's not generating `<table>` tags. Also, the code in your question cannot possibly be the full `View` code -- Razor would not be able to parse it this way. Here's an article about Razor in MVC 4: http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/08/mvc-4-razor-view-engine-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class HtmlElements
{
    public static HtmlTable Table(this HtmlHelper ht, string classe)
    {
        var table = new HtmlTable();
        table.Attributes.Add("class", classe);
        return table;
    }
}
```